# SQL 2012 locating duplicate column entries in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL 2012 and trying to identify rows where the SourceDataID column has two unique entries in the PartyCode column, and I'm having difficulties.

```
SELECT PartyCode, SourceDataID, count (*) as CNT
FROM CustomerOrderLocation (nolock) 
GROUP BY PartyCode, SourceDataID
HAVING (Count(PartyCode)>1)
ORDER BY PartyCode
```

Results are returning as such:

W3333   948_O   31
(party code/sourcedataid/CNT)

This is showing me the total entries where the `Partycode` and the `SourceDataID` are listed together in the table. However, I need it to show a count of any instances where `W333` lists `948_O` as the `SourceDataID` more than once.

I'm not having luck structuring the query to pull the results I am looking to get. How can I do this?

Comment: What results do you want to get?   I don't understand the difference between what you're getting and what you say you want.

Comment: What is being returned is the number of records in the table per PartyCode / SourceDataID combination.   What I need it to return is all records where more than 1 partycode is tied to a single sourceDataID.  So if W3333 AND W3332 were both using 948_O as their SourceDataID, I would need the query to advise me that there were duplicates of that, rather than W333 and 948_O have been used together in the table 31 times total.  Each SourceDataID should only have 1 PartyCode associated to it.

Comment: Yes, and that's what it looks like you are asking for.

Comment: Can't you just change your Having to be SouceDataID?

Answer (score 1):

A `CTE` coupled with the `PARTITION BY` function is helpful in finding duplicates of this manner. Code below:

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT PartyCode, SourceDataID,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY SourceDataID ORDER BY SourceDataID) RN
FROM CustomerOrderLocation (NOLOCK))

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

This should return every duplicate PartyCode attached to a SourceDataID.

If you want to see the entire result, change the last `SELECT` statement to:

```
SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY PartyCode, RN
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone.  I did not do the best job of describing the issue but this is the query I ended up creating to get my result set.

```
 ;with cte1 (sourcedataid, partycode) as (select sourcedataid, partycode from customerorderparty (nolock) group by PartyCode, SourceDataID)

select count(sourcedataid), sourcedataid from cte1 group by sourcedataid having count(sourcedataid) >1
```